# Get dict from query string/post data in Tornado web server?

Tags: python, url, dictionary, query-string, tornado

Maybe I am missing something, this should be very easy thing if I code PHP, but weird I cannot handle this basic thing in python tornado web server.

Tornado web server gets a request like this :

**http://example.com/?a[x]=1&a[y]=2&a[z]=3&b=4**

I need to get **a** as a dict in python

In Tornado:

```
class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        print self.get_argument('a') #failed 
        print self.get_arguments('a') #failed
```

Any ready to use solution to this problem, or have I to code my custom method for parsing this from **self.request.query_arguments**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

PHP (and I think Ruby) may treat brackets in argument names specially, but this is not standard. As far as python and tornado are concerned, these are simply arguments named `a[x]`, `a[y]`, etc. To reassemble them into a dictionary you'll need to parse them out of self.request.query_arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`self.get_argument('a[x]')`

But never seen any one who write an url like this

You may need json dump string and warp it within http body